# Prestashop - Increasing Amount in Dropdown Shopping Cart

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using ps_shopping cart module. I want to show increase and decrease amount button in dropdown shopping cart like below.

[image]

I copied codes from shopping cart page to dropdown cart. I showed it. There is a problem, If click increase or decrease button on homepage, amount is changed but then these buttons are hidden. (If I increase or decrease amount on cart page, there is no problem.)

before increase:

[image]

after increase:

[image]